# ActiveX DLL called from Python thread

Tags: python, multithreading, activex

I have an ActiveX (COM) DLL that makes windows system calls (such as ReadFile() and WriteFile()). It works fine from the main Python GUI thread. But crashes my Python GUI when called from a thread. I am doing some research online and am thinking I need to do something with the GIL. Am I on the right track? Or please point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say anything without seeing the code, but chances are that either:

1. Your ActiveX simply does not support multithreading (many of them do not) and you try to work with the object from different threads.
2. The DLL containing the ActiveX performs some per-thread initialization, but when you call it from another thread it's not initialized.

Anyway, I can't say anything about GIL, but having dealt with ActiveX in my past, I believe that most likely the source of the problem is the ActiveX.

Comment: The DLL is apartment threaded (STA). It works when called in by C# GUI.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261361%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: If I create a new instance of the DLL in the thread, it works in Python. Also, in order to not block the main thread in C#, a new instance needs to be created in the thread. Is there any way to avoid creating a new instance of the DLL?

Answer (score 0):

As Vladimir mentioned, I might be that your COM component is not multithreaded safe, you might test the "Apartment" type your DLL is registered in. This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9190/Understanding-The-COM-Single-Threaded-Apartment-Pa) gives a good overview about this issue.

Comment: Should be "Free" exist as ThreadingModel, just try "Apartment". I got this issue once, and this tip saved my life..:-)